# How to delete a test record from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've been testing my website and notice the elastic search has indexed those test records.
My Question, how can I query elasticsearch to delete the test record?

Answer (score 1):

Just issue a HTTP POST in the following model :

```
POST /{index/_delete_by_query

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use postman or any rest client for posting, make sure you set content-type:application/json